# python API paging loops becomes infinite

Tags: python, while-loop

I cant understand why this while loop is infinite(it seems so cause it just gets stuck)
It increments the page number and supposed to stop the requests once it gets an empty body (no more results). I check the body with the length of the response body

```
baseurl = "https://jobs.github.com/positions.json"

def get_number_of_jobs(technology):
    number_of_jobs = 0
    page=1
    payload={"description":technology,"page":page}
    new_results=1
    while new_results>0:
        r=requests.get(baseurl,payload)
        new_results =len(r.json())
        page+=1
        number_of_jobs+=(len(r.json()))
         
    return technology,number_of_jobs
```

Comment: You never update the variable `payload` and keep requesting the same page

Answer (score 2):

Your `payload={"description":"php","page":page}` should be inside the `while` loop because it has `page` that is otherwise always 1.

Your code should be this:

```
baseurl = "https://jobs.github.com/positions.json"

def get_number_of_jobs(technology):
    number_of_jobs = 0
    page=1
    new_results=1
    while new_results>0:
        payload={"description":technology,"page":page}
        r=requests.get(baseurl,payload)
        new_results =len(r.json())
        page+=1
        number_of_jobs+=(len(r.json()))
         
    return technology,number_of_jobs
```

Comment: I put the payload variable inside the while loop as you said and it worked...silly me...thanks!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Answer (score 0):

The loop is infinite because the condition `new_results > 0` is always true.

And as @DYZ noted, the `payload` variable never changes, so you're perpetually requesting the same page, therefore no values change in each iteration.

Comment: the payload uses a page value that is incremented on each request. and the new_results is supposed to become zero when the length of the response body is zero

Comment: Yes but you need to update your `payload` for each call so that you call correct page which you can't do if you are stuck in a loop :)

Comment: Correct, but you're never reassigning `payload`. @DavidDelač's answer will best serve your needs.